# How to update two models in one form in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Okay, so first of all the situation is not quite easy as in the title. So I want to create form which can create object based on Cycle model and update only one field in Post model (field in question is 'cycle_title'). What is more its isn't only one post where this post have to be updated but there are several of it (all post's titles are saved in Cycle.post).

views

```py
class CycleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'blog/cycle_form.html'
    form_class = CycleForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse_user = self.request.user
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': reverse_user})
```

forms

```py
class CycleForm(BSModalForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['posts'].queryset = Post.objects.filter(author=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Cycle
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'posts']
        widgets = {
            'posts': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

models

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = MDTextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cycle_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

```py
class Cycle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="Brak opisu")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

I was thinking about a solution like this:

```
for i in form.cleaned_data['posts']:
    post = Post.objects.get(title=form.cleaned_data['title'][i])
    post.cycle_title = form.cleaned_data['title']
    post.save()
```

But I doubt if it is good way to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package has been built just to handle this exact scenario, `django-shapeshifter`. You can find it here:

https://github.com/kennethlove/django-shapeshifter

The basic premise is to create two model forms, then include them in the same template. The example given shows how to update a `User` and a `Profile` model from the same view and form. It sounds like that is a match for your problem. Full disclosure, I'm a contributor to this package, but is was created exactly because of frustrations like your own!